# How can I pass the value from my function to another component in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a react application that shows details about the pokemon you searched. So I have a Home component which has an input field + submit button.
I want to render my api call in my Main component.

The question that I have is : How can I pass the value from this input field that is located in my home component to my main component when I enter submit?

[home component details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsBtF.png)

I need this value to update my pokemon name state in my Main component in order to get the pokemon name for my fetch call.

I need this value to be stored inside my 'searchValue' state.
[Main component details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLpyw.png)

any tips?

Comment: Try to rethink your component hierarchy, and think about where state should be stored and how data flow. Input can be treated as stateless and accept onChange & onSubmit as props.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can achieve this by Using ref in reactjs , Inside your Main Component you need to make a reference, like :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
}

// Delete the reference once component is unmounted

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
}
```

And then create a method , which will receive the values from a the `Home` component and then `setState` like :

```
method(values) {
    this.setState({ searchValue: values });
}
```

Now inside your Home component you need to reference method component before your input like , (You can amend it accordignly)

```
import Home from './Home'

<Home onRef={ref => (this.home = ref)} />
<Form onSubmit={e => { this.onSubmit(e) }}
```

Make sure to add `onSubmit` method inside main component which will send the values to `Home` Component

```
onSubmit = values => {
    this.home.method(values);
}
```

You can read more about Ref and the DOM on [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you to take a look at [redux](https://redux.js.org/) which is great tool for state management. `Redux` will ensure you have a single source of truth.

What you will have to do is create an [Action](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) which would dispatch an event to update the state, a [Reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) which would update the state (value of the search-key in `redux-store`). Your `Main` component will read the data from the API (Same `Action`-`Reducer` way) & render it without having to bother about the current state. I can explain the whole architecture in detail if you are more interested. This architecture will have less bugs & clear flow of information including shared state between components.

I know this sounds bit too complex but its worth a try if your application is growing.

Few suggestions:
Your Main component has too much of logic. Components should have least logic as possible so they are more deterministic. Please also read about [React Stateless functional components](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc)

Here are some links if you wish to take `redux` path

- [10-tips-for-better-redux-architecture](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/10-tips-for-better-redux-architecture-69250425af44)
- [Redux Best Practices](https://medium.com/@kylpo/redux-best-practices-eef55a20cc72)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean with has too much of logic? That I can write the same component with less code?

Comment: yup, component must be dumb enough to just render values from the state & don't have so much of logic. Read Search Data from the API, update the redux-store, modify it on the fly using `selector` to suit needs of the component.